# WSL calling VScode and then paused

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I type `code .` and the command line start waiting.

Type Ctrl C didn't work, like the following picture.

[image]

It'll wait until I shutdown VScode.

Hope someone can help me.

I didn't encountered this problem on another computer, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Installing WSL Extension will solve this issue.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl

Comment: But why will it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).